# Trouble deploying to Heroku -- logs included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm running a Rails 3.09 Ruby 1.92 App on Bamboo stack on Heroku. The app works just fine in production mode running locally without problems. I'm trying to diagnose why the app won't run on Heroku. I'm getting a 500 Error Miscellaneous Server Error. Has anyone seen something like what's in the logs before?

This is my logs...

https://gist.github.com/2655795

Update: here's the updated log: https://gist.github.com/2655991

Update: I enabled config.whiny_nils = true in my production.rb file and now I am getting this error on Heroku but not running locally on my environment in production. I'm using Postgres locally.

`G::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
: INSERT INTO "sessions"`

Comment: just have to check, but you *did* `migrate` your database, right?

Comment: Have you precompiled your assets?  I notice that the first error seems to be on an image not being found.

Comment: rjz: i ran my migrations.
Dave Collins: i'm running rails 3.09. I get an error when I `bundle exec rake:assets precompile` as in unknown task. I think Asset Pipeline was Rails 3.1+.

Comment: I'm going to upload the gemfile.lock. Think it might be something with a gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're migrating from MySQL.

Your table doesn't have a `sequence`, what pg uses instead of `autoincrement`. Instead of creating your table's `id` column with `"id" integer NOT NULL,`, use `"id" serial,`. Postgres will mention it's creating a sequence for you, and you can run `\d tablename` in the command line to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Log into Heroku and run the following:

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

It looks like you may have old session data laying around.

If you haven't done it before, you log into your Heroku instance by running:

```
heroku run bash --app my_app
```

Comment: Hi Kevin I tried that and it still is not working. 

`PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
: INSERT INTO "sessions" ("session_id", "data", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('34322a201a85fc70a26209891528b989', 'BAh7B0kiFWN1cnJlbnRfY2F0ZWdvcnkGOgZFRkkiKTExM2EyM2NiLTFiZTEt
NGZjOS05NWIyLTNiNTllMDc3NWZiOQY7AFRJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJ
IjF2bEd3anJqK1djSG9TNlgwd3NjQUgxWjhpcURGMkxkaEhPMXVKSC90Tkpr
PQY7AEY=
', '2012-05-14 23:48:02.184057', '2012-05-14 23:48:02.184057')`